# Extracting image(s) beyond column Z returns a SheetImageLoader error in Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an xlsm file where images are located beyond Z column. I want to extract images from this file by using openpyxl-image-loader:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsm') sheet1 = wb['Лист3'] image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet1)
```

but I run into a problem in [my] function which returns the error:

> SheetImageLoader IndexError: string index out of range

I've seen a solution on GitHub taht said to edit a row in the library code from

```
col = string.ascii_uppercase\[image.anchor.\_from.col\]
```

to

```
col = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(image.anchor.\_from.col + 1)
```

I've edited, but it doesn't work. Is there other solution?

[image]

Comment: Looking at the `sheet_image_loader.py` file, when you  change the line to `col = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(image.anchor.\_from.col + 1)` you'd then also need to import openpyxl. Did you add that import to the file too? What [error] message did you get after modifying the file?

Comment: Yeah, I did it and received the same error

Comment: The same 'index out of range' error? Did you definitely change or disable the original line and sure its the copy your app is using. You can add a print line before the modded line, `print(image.anchor._from.col)` to see the its the correct value being passed to `openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter()`

Comment: You are erroring on the row not column, so haven't even got to the problem of columns past Z. What row is the image on? As before you can still print the line to see what value is returned, `print(image.anchor._from.row)` instead.

Comment: but the problem occures every time when pictures cross Z column. When pictures in A-Z zone, SheetImageLoader works right. In my case the picture is located in AA1 cell. I added print(image.anchor._from.row), now it points to this line in error text box

Comment: Sorry there is a errant full stop at the end of the line  `print(image.anchor._from.col)` in my answer code sample that would cause a syntax error (corrected now). So you are now getting a different error on a different line? You haven't posted an updated screen shot

Comment: Or just forget about importing SheetImageLoader  and run that block of code as part of your code, see my answer code sample 2

Comment: Now it works!!! I tried to run the code via jupyter notebook and it worked! Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

This is my modded sheet_image_loader.py file

```
"""
Contains a SheetImageLoader class that allow you to loadimages from a sheet
"""

import io
import string
import openpyxl

from PIL import Image


class SheetImageLoader:
    """Loads all images in a sheet"""
    _images = {}

    def __init__(self, sheet):
        """Loads all sheet images"""
        sheet_images = sheet._images
        for image in sheet_images:
            print(image.anchor._from.row)  # print the anchor row value
            row = image.anchor._from.row + 1
            print(image.anchor._from.col)  # Print the anchor column value 
            col = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(image.anchor._from.col + 1)
            print(col)  # print the Column letter from get column letter
            # col = string.ascii_uppercase[image.anchor._from.col]
            self._images[f'{col}{row}'] = image._data

    def image_in(self, cell):
        """Checks if there's an image in specified cell"""
        return cell in self._images

    def get(self, cell):
        """Retrieves image data from a cell"""
        if cell not in self._images:
            raise ValueError("Cell {} doesn't contain an image".format(cell))
        else:
            image = io.BytesIO(self._images[cell]())
            return Image.open(image)
```

This is my test code sample 1

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsm')
sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(sheet1)
```

The image is inserted in cell 'AD1', this is the output.

```
0
29
AD
```

**Just try running the code in your block**
Code Sample 2

```
import openpyxl


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsm')
sheet1 = wb['Sheet1']

sheet_images = sheet1._images
for image in sheet_images:
    print(image.anchor._from.row)  # print the anchor row value
    row = image.anchor._from.row + 1
    print(image.anchor._from.col)  # Print the anchor column value
    col = openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_letter(image.anchor._from.col + 1)
    print(col)  # print the Column letter from get column letter
```

Output should be the same.

Comment: I've tried it right now, but still no success  :(  I've added a screenshoot to my question text

Comment: The answer shows why there is no need for an extra library just to extract images.

Answer (score -3):

To extract images from an xlsm file using openpyxl-image-loader, you need to make sure that the file is loaded with the read_only and keep_vba flags set to True. This will preserve the images and their anchors in the workbook. For example:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader
wb = load_workbook (filename = "file.xlsm", read_only = True, keep_vba = True)
ws = wb ["Sheet1"]
image_loader = SheetImageLoader (ws)
```

Then, you can use the image_loader.get (row, col) method to get the image at a given cell. The row and col arguments should be integers, not strings. For example, to get the image at cell AA1, you can use:

```py
image = image_loader.get (1, 27) # 27 is the column number for AA
```

The image_loader.get (row, col) method will return a PIL Image object if there is an image at the cell, or None if there is no image. You can then save the image to a file or display it as you wish. For example:

```py
if image is not None:
    image.save ("image.png")
else:
    print ("No image at this cell")
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: the problem is occuring during running the row image_loader = SheetImageLoader (ws)
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: I think, maybe I should shift all cells to A-Z columns diapason..

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer, but just to clarify; it should not be necessary to load the file with the read_only and keep_vba flags set to True to obtain the image details.